# Подключение нужной модели при ajax запросе

Tags: laravel

Всем привет!

Начал изучение laravel5, и вот такой вопрос возник.

У меня есть контроллер, API, который отвечает на ajax запросы. Но не могу понять как подключить нужную модель, в зависимости от запроса.

```
// Код контроллера
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Message;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index($action){
        $messages = Message::count();

        $data = array(
            'status'    =>  'success',
            'action'    => 'action'
        );
        return json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Вот у меня подключена одна модель

```
use App\Models\Message;
```

Я её могу использовать, все чудесно. Но, у меня будет должны записи браться из разных моделей, как их подключать в зависимости от $action-a? Не хочу просто сразу подключать 10моделей через `use`

```
use App\Models\Message;
use App\Models\Users;
use App\Models\Servers;
use App\Models\Caegory;
```

Я просто не знаю, как правильно делается, вот и спрашиваю, может в корне не правильно делаю.. Прошу тапками не кидать :)

Comment: Если модели связаны между собой, то можно использовать метод `with`. Если нет, то switch-ем по экшену пройтись

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что проблема уже в том что у тебя одно действие отдает разные модели! это как то не по RestAPI принципу, запомни, в идеале каждый маршрут отдает свою сущность.
Ну а если ты все же в одном действии отдаешь разные модели, то нет ничего страшного, что ты их добавишь в use.